# How to create a tab delimited string for QR code?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, qr-code

I have been tasked with populating a QR Code with a tab delimited string in classic ASP - not getting anywhere fast.

```
Dim tabForQRCode
tabForQRCode = strSourceCode & vbTab & strSourceCode & vbTab & vbTab & strSiteCode & vbTab & reference & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab & "1" & vbTab & vbTab 
tabForQRCode = tabForQRCode & "y" & vbTab & "n" & vbTab & "n" & vbTab & "n" & vbTab & strTestCode& vbTab & secondName & vbTab & firstName & vbTab 
tabForQRCode = tabForQRCode & gender &  vbTab & dob & vbTab & vbTab & telephone & vbTab & "y" & vbTab & vbTab & addressLine1 & vbTab
tabForQRCode = tabForQRCode & addressLine2 & vbTab & addressLine3 & vbTab & email & vbTab & ethnic & vbTab & symptoms3 & vbTab & symptoms4
tabForQRCode = Server.URLEncode(tabForQRCode)
```

I am using

```
https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=200x200&data=" & tabForQRCode
```

My problem is that the generated QR just shows spaces. I have suggested that the client accepts XML but I suspect the answer will be no.

Any ideas? Would I have more success writing my own class or DLL?

I have tried replacing `vbTab` with `chr(9)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're sending a web request, use [percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) for your tab characters:

```
Dim tabForQRCode
tabForQRCode = strSourceCode & "%09" & strSourceCode & "%09%09" & strSiteCode & "%09" & reference & "%09%09%091%09%09"
tabForQRCode = tabForQRCode & "y%09n%09n%09n%09" & strTestCode & ...
...
```

Comment: I've tried this but now my qr code just has %09 after each item 

    test%09test%09%09

Comment: @ItalloSan: It worked just fine when I tested it with a sample string `foo%09bar%09baz`. Please provide evidence.

Comment: Thanks - the client reports that their QR software reads this just fine - thanks for your help.